# How to do url/view routing with Mobservable, React and possibly React-Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url-routing, react-router

I'm looking into [mobservable](http://mweststrate.github.io/mobservable/) but I'm having some trouble coming up with a good model to do url routing.

Because of how mobservable works with React using a standard `react-router` does nothing when you change the url. Only if we crudely pass the url path down into the Handler stack to make them reactive do I see some changes.

I feel this needs a different approach. Of course I could hack some custom thing but I kinda like react-routers way of nesting the urls and the solid Location/Link features.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working a (non public) project that uses both mobservable and react-router. That setup is basically as follows:

1. Create all your routes, but give them all the same handler, your root component.
2. Introduce reactive state that stores your ui state (like, currently open document for example)
3. in the [router.run](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Router.run) callback, use the data that is passed in (the second argument) to update your ui state and to kick off the necessary data retrieval and such. In the end of the callback, just render your handler. Depending on your further setup of the root component you want to pass it the ui state or nothing at all.

For us that setup worked fine so far, so please let me know if you run into any trouble.

**EDIT**

Another setup using Director can be found in the [Mobservable TodoMVC](https://github.com/mweststrate/mobservable-react-todomvc/blob/master/src/components/todoApp.js) example

Answer (score 1):

Linking this because I found it helpful.  I am basically following the approach out here: https://github.com/contacts-mvc/mobx-react-typescript/blob/master/src/components/ContactDetails/index.tsx.

Initialize the store/model in the app's index page or wherever the routes are defined. Then pass the initialized store to the component. Inside the component `componentWillMount` grab the ID off the route and pass it to a function to load your data.

If you already had data loaded then make a method that changes the selected item. Make sure that select item property is observed and it should automatically update the UI. I think that is what @mweststrate means by UI state.